# Django CSRF verification failed on form validation after login with Ajax

Tags: django, ajax, authentication, csrf

My context, I fill my form, I have the possiblity to save the values in the database if I am log in.

When I click on the Log in button, I open a bootstrap modal form to log in and I use Ajax/Jquery for the log in process.

I understood that the CSRF token change after login, that's why when I validate my form (POST), I have the message: "Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." because I didn't refresh my page.

What I can't figure out, is how can I refresh this token without loosing all the datas I already filled in my form?

Comment: Try changing the login code in a way that it returns a new CSRF token which you acquire with the get_token() method mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#how-it-works) in the docs. Then you replace old token with this one.

Comment: Thank you soooo much Borut! It works! You're rule!!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add `{% csrf_token %}` to your template in html body
Then get the `csrf_token` value in a variable and pass it to ajax request like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

And to get `csrf_token` in a variable in js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// using jQuery
var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
</script>
```

For more follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request

Comment: Thank you Shourav for your answer. But you describe how to send the CSRF token through Ajax, that part already works, my problem is that the token changed when I logged in the user (with Ajax), so I can't submit my main form anymore without refreshing the page and so loosing my data previously filled!

Comment: You can use multiple csrf_token. Like if you have two seperate forms to handle login and your_form. You should include csrf_token two times